# printing all partitions of a number

Tags: c++

I have a small problem. I'm working on a project that have to print all the partitions of an integer, in this way. For example:

```
5 = 5
5 = 4 + 1
5 = 3 + 2
5 = 3 + 1 + 1
5 = 2 + 2 + 1
5 = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
5 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
.
```

So there is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int p[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << p[i]<<" + " ;
    cout<<endl;
}

void printAllUniqueParts(int n) {
    int p[n];
    int k = 0;
    p[k] = n;

    while (true)
    {
        cout<<n<<" = ";
        printArray(p, k + 1);

        int rem_val = 0;
        while (k >= 0 && p[k] == 1)
        {
            rem_val += p[k];
            k--;
        }
        if (k < 0)
            return;
        p[k]--;
        rem_val++;
        while (rem_val > p[k])
        {
            p[k + 1] = p[k];
            rem_val = rem_val - p[k];
            k++;
        }
        p[k + 1] = rem_val;
        k++;
    }
}
```

It prints them in a correct order, but the problem is that it prints an extra + at the end. I can't find the problem. It may be very small bug, but I cant see it. Could you please check this out, and share your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Only print the "+" if you are not at the end of the range.

`cout << p[i]; if (i+1 < n) cout << " + " ;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very obvious:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << p[i]<<" + " ;
```

The code you wrote prints a `+` after every number. So that's exactly what it's going to do. Just because you don't want a `+` to appear after the last number, that's not going to happen unless the program is coded to do so.

There are several common, simplest techniques for formatting this kind of output. The simplest one is not to print the `+` after the number, but before it, and simply not print it before the first number. It's often logically simpler to take a non-default option for the first step, instead of the last one, since you do not have to figure out which one is the last one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     if (i > 0)
          cout << " + ";

     cout << p[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you verry much my friend.